# How do I remove an IP address from an interface?

Tags: networking

I was setting up a kubernetes cluster and accidentally used the wrong IP address range for a command.
Below is the output (trimmed) that shows my problem and reason for the question:

```
$ ip addr show
. . . 
6: weave: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1376 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:ea:80:6d:10:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ==========================================================
    THIS needs to be deleted
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global weave
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  ==========================================================
    inet 192.168.4.1/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global weave
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b4ea:80ff:fe6d:106c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I need to remove the `192.168.0.1/24` address from this interface.

I'm running `Ubuntu 20.04`.

If it matters, the way this was created was using a kubernetes command as shown below:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')&password-secret=weave-passwd&env.IPALLOC_RANGE=192.168.0.0/24"
```

There were several other steps prior to this. See
https://blog.alexellis.io/kubernetes-in-10-minutes/

## Searching for solution

(Q) How can I remove an IP address from an interface in linux?

- https://superuser.com/questions/153559/how-can-i-clear-the-ip-address-of-ethernet-interface-without-cycling-the-interfa/1060958 - This might be the answer I'm looking for

If that is the answer, please mark this as a duplicate.  I'm just trying to make sure I have the write command before I mess something else up. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually on the superuser.com site https://superuser.com/a/153613/331605.  I'm just giving credit where it is due.

I used the following command and it removed the extra IP address that was assigned:

```
sudo ip addr del 192.168.0.1/24 dev weave
```

After this the `ip addr show` shows the following:

```
ip addr show
6: weave: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1376 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:ea:80:6d:10:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.1/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global weave
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b4ea:80ff:fe6d:106c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Make sure to re-deploy weave. Or at least, remove the objects created by your kubectl apply. Otherwise, rebooting, weave would start back, using the same subnet/IP.

Comment: @SYN, Thanks.  I actually re-deployed weave using the 2nd IP address (`192.168.4.1`) and when I noticed that this didn't remove the 1st one, that is why I asked my question.  Thanks for comment, I'll have to look at the master kube-master when it reboots to verify that everything is _still_ correct.

Answer (score 2):

On FreeBSD, you can use the `delete` option with [ifconfig(8)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ifconfig) to remove an IP address from an interface, e.g.,

```
ifconfig mce0 192.168.0.1/24 delete
```

I'm posting this answer for completeness as neither the title nor the tags indicate any specific OS.